# Rotación automática de imágenes en pygame

Tags: python, pygame, logrotate

No consigo que la imagen gire y se posiciona en unas coordenadas que no son. Este mismo código de rotación, en una ventana a parte, funciona perfectamente. El error está en que no aumenta progresivamente el current_angle, se queda en 0.02, no consigo ver por qué.

```
                if len(self.player_group) == 0:   

                    self.surf = pg.image.load("resources/nave/nave.png").convert_alpha()
                    self.current_angle = 0
                    self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(center=(700, 300))

                   if self.current_angle <= 180:    
                      self.current_angle += 0.02

                  self.texto.screen.blit(self.rot_center(self.surf,self.current_angle), self.rect)

         pg.display.flip()

         pg.display.update()



 def rot_center(self,image, angle):
     orig_rect = image.get_rect()
     rot_image = pg.transform.rotate(image, angle)
     rot_rect = orig_rect.copy()
     rot_rect.center = rot_image.get_rect().center
     rot_image = rot_image.subsurface(rot_rect).copy()
     return rot_image
```

Answer (score 0):

La posicion ya la he corregido cambiando

```
(center=(700, 300))
```

a

```
(x=700, y=300)
```

Rotacion operativa, la variable current_angle, debía estar en el init, y no ahí.